# StackExchange.Exceptional not logging exceptions from Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, blazor-server-side, stackexchange.exceptional

I have a Blazor Server-Side app running with `.NET 5.0` and I'm trying to switch from [ElmahCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ElmahCore/) to [Exceptional](https://github.com/NickCraver/StackExchange.Exceptional).
But I can't get it to log Blazor exceptions.
When I throw an exception in a MVC controller it gets logged, but if I throw one in e.g. `OnAfterRenderAsync` nothing gets logged.

What do I need to configure to get Blazor exceptions logged with Exceptional?

Also in ElmahCore I could use `ElmahExtensions.RiseError(exception);` to log an exception I catched/handled in code but still wanted to show up in the error-log. Is there something similar for Exceptional?

I configured Exceptional with the default configuration from [HERE](https://nickcraver.com/StackExchange.Exceptional/AspDotNetCore).

Comment: Cross-Post: https://github.com/NickCraver/StackExchange.Exceptional/issues/209

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded the package first:

```
Install-Package StackExchange.Exceptional.AspNetCore -Version 2.2.17
```

Next, add the Exceptional tag configuration to the appsettings.json file, which contains the connection string used to store errors in the database:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Exceptional": {
    "Store": {
      "ApplicationName": "Test",
      "Type": "SQL",
      "ConnectionString": "Your Db"
    }
  }
}
```

Registering AddExceptional service in ConfigureServices Method:

```
  services.AddExceptional(Configuration.GetSection("Exceptional"), settings =>
    {
        settings.UseExceptionalPageOnThrow = HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
    });
```

After adding ConfigureServices next, we are going to add “UseExceptional” middleware in Configure method.

Adding app.UseExceptional(); Middleware in Configure method to handle errors:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            app.UseExceptional();
            .....
}
```

Then I wrote a throw exception `throw new NotImplementedException();`

Then you can see the record:

[image]

According to the article you provided, it should be done.Which side did you have a problem with?

Comment: the original issue is that exceptions from Blazor are not captured